# Obtaining the total amount between two dates for every user code in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm currently learning how to navigate the Pandas library in Python, and came across a bit of a struggle today.

Essentially, to keep it short, I have a Dataframe for a couple different subscription services that contains the following information (apologies for the formatting):

User code / Event / Event Date / Monthly price

So a couple of example rows would be something like this:

```
223 / Subscription Start / 2020-10-03 / 15.00

223 / Subscription End / 2021-12-02 / 15.00

224 / Subscription Start / 2020-10-03 / 12.00

225 / Subscription Start / 2020-10-04 / 13.00
```

And if there's no Subscription End, then it's assumed that the person is still subscribed to the service.

My question is, is there a way, using Pandas, to calculate the total amount spent in monthly fees for all users up until a period of time?

So, for example, if we have three different users, all three subscribed on the same date, in March 2020. One of them cancelled the subscription after two billing cycles, while the other two still are subscribed, and it's been five billing cycles. The expected output would be:

```
 5 * (Subscription price person 1) +

 5 * (Subscription price person 2) + 

2 * (Subscription price person 3) 

= 
Total amount.
```

I want to know if there's a method of obtaining this information in Pandas.

Thanks a ton for reading up 'til here!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have this dataframe:

```
   User code               Event  Event Date  Monthly price
0        223  Subscription Start  2020-10-03           15.0
1        223    Subscription End  2021-12-02           15.0
2        224  Subscription Start  2020-10-03           12.0
3        225  Subscription Start  2020-10-04           13.0
```

Then you can pivot the table:

```
df = (
    df.pivot(
        index=["User code", "Monthly price"],
        columns="Event",
        values="Event Date",
    )
    .fillna(pd.Timestamp.now())
    .reset_index()
)
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
Event  User code  Monthly price           Subscription End Subscription Start
0            223           15.0 2021-12-02 00:00:00.000000         2020-10-03
1            224           12.0 2021-04-14 00:20:28.427278         2020-10-03
2            225           13.0 2021-04-14 00:20:28.427278         2020-10-04
```

Then to compute the fee, just do a difference between `Subscription Start` and `Subscription End` columns and multiply with `Monthly price`:

```
df["Total amount"] = (
    df["Subscription End"].dt.to_period("M")
    - df["Subscription Start"].dt.to_period("M")
).apply(lambda x: x.n) * df["Monthly price"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
Event  User code  Monthly price           Subscription End Subscription Start  Total amount
0            223           15.0 2021-12-02 00:00:00.000000         2020-10-03         210.0
1            224           12.0 2021-04-14 00:22:48.941899         2020-10-03          72.0
2            225           13.0 2021-04-14 00:22:48.941899         2020-10-04          78.0
```

Comment: @Arthur Try to convert the Event Date column to DateTime before running the code: `df['Event Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event Date'])`

Comment: Thanks a ton for the time spared, Andrej. One last question, is there a way to replace the .fillna to use a specific date instead of the current time?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you can use for example `pd.Timestamp("2020-10-23")` (change the date string as you want)